# How do I select a minimum occurrence of the characters I want to select?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, the characters c,a,t should be selected from a string such that at least one occurrence of each character has happened. 
My regex : `/[o{1,}w{1,}l{1,}]/gmi`
I cannot get it to select a minimum occurrence of at least 1.

```
kkcnjnkannt //true as c,a and t are there at least once.
kkjcsnknna //false as c and a are there but not t.
```

Comment: Try using positive lookaheads. `^(?=.*c)^(?=.*a)^(?=.*t).*$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1IPuRM/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `[o{1,}w{1,}l{1,}]` consists of a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which is the same as `[o1,wl{}]`

To check if there is a `c`, `a` and `t` in your string, you could use 3 times a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

`^(?=.*c)^(?=.*a)^(?=.*t).*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1IPuRM/1)